# Age of Passengers Histogram

Tags: excel, charts, histogram

I have a data set that has ages listed and the number of passengers who are that age.  I need to create a histogram to show that data. I only seem to get a histogram chart output of 1 column of the data, not both though. See image below.

How do I get essentially a column chart (but as a histogram) to show the quantity of passengers in each age group?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Ss9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a clustered column chart, with the age column as the horizontal axis.
you can reduce the gap width for the look of a histogram.

[image]
[image]
[image]